# Custom Drawing Text C#

Tags: c#, fonts, textbox, customization

I have a TextBox in my Form and I am drawing a string into it as below.

```
Font myFont = new Font("Arial",18F,FontStyle.Regular,GraphicsUnit.Point,128);
Graphics g = myTextBox.CreateGraphics();
Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
g.DrawString("Item Drawn with DrawString",myFont ,b,new PointF(1,1));
```

The string displayed in the TextBox. Then I tried below code

```
 Font myFont = new Font("Arial",18F,FontStyle.Regular,GraphicsUnit.Point,128);
 Graphics g = myTextBox.CreateGraphics();
 TextRenderer.DrawText(g,"Item Drawn with DrawText",myFont,new Point(1,1),Color.Red);
```

Here the problem comes. Even though two methods `g.DrawString()` and `TextRenderer.DrawText()` uses same font, there is a difference in font style. That is some characters are rendered differently. If I use "1" instead of "128" in the font both methods will render characters as unique.

If I change `GdiCharSet(128)` value in font, while using `g.DrawString()` method there will be no effect. My question is why  `g.DrawString()` method excludes `GdiCharSet` value?

Answer (score 0):

Because of this:

> The gdiCharSet parameter takes a value from the list defined in the Windows SDK header file WinGDI.h. Windows Forms applications support TrueType fonts and have limited support for OpenType fonts. If the familyName parameter specifies a font that is not installed on the machine running the application or is not supported, Microsoft Sans Serif will be substituted.

([From the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/h7c7wc9z.aspx))

Since Arial is a TrueType font and it supports Unicode, you shouldn't need to be setting the GDI Char Set, as far as I am aware.